# How to distinguish 3 different types of comments with Intellij

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, comments

In Code::Blocks I'm able to define 3 different types of comments each with a particular style:

```
/* */ Block comment
//    Line comment
///   Alternate line comment
```

Is there anyway to implement a feature like this with Intellij? I am using Android Studio for reference. (I am not including JavaDocs comments as part of the 3 that I would like to define.) I would like to have an additional definition of a line comment similar to Code::Blocks so that I can have 3 different types of style that I can change.

Answer (score 2):

There is no feature in IntelliJ IDEA that would allow you to define an additional comment style for Java files. However, you can write a plugin that will highlight any code patterns (including your alternative line comment style) in any way you like.

Comment: Would that be really hard to write? Can you point me somewhere that would help me with that?

Comment: No, this should't be too hard. Basically you'd need to provide an implementation of [Annotator](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/analysis-api/src/com/intellij/lang/annotation/Annotator.java). See [here](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/index.html) for general information on IntelliJ plugin development.

Comment: OK Thanks! I'll look into it.